# How to build an old library with obsoleted idioms?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, static-libraries, standards

I want to build an old open-source library ('speech-tools' from [here](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/downloads/festival/1.95/)) for the embedded device. The library is a mix of c and c++ code. For device I must use gcc 4.4 or up. The library, however, seems to use very old code, it contains `#include <iostream.h>` everywhere and not using std:: namespace and so on.

So the question is: is it possible to make GCC 4 remember good old days and build pre-standart C code as well as GCC 3 did?  I do not want to tinker the source code of the library because it is huge, and I don't want to add subtle bugs (they are in abundance already).

I have tried -std=c98 and c++98 and of cause it didn't help because this is pre-98 code form. However, some guys on the net claim to have build it with GCC4.5, and didn't mention tinkering the source.

Comment: As far as I know, the `<iostream.h>` dates back to the early ninetess... What is the extent of the library? Would it be a big effort to update it, replacing headers and stuff?

Comment: sorry, I erroneously wrote c++ instad of C. It is C and C++ intermixed library.

Comment: Please update your post, this is confusing talking about `<iostream.h>` and yet your library is a C-library...

Comment: For a long time, g++ came with a header `<iostream.h>`, which included `<iostream>` and then did enough `using` to make everything in it visible in global namespace.  If the version of g++ you are using doesn't have this (I don't know when they stopped supporting it), then you can write the header yourself.  For use in a single application, just `#include <iostream> using namespace std;` (on two lines, of course) might be sufficient.  (For the rest, most of the changes in the language are upwards compatible, so unless the library is making extensive use of templates, you might be OK.)

Comment: bash.d: Yes, fixed the text. What confuses me most is that I see it in repositiories of modern Linuxes. Guess will have to ask package maintainers how they did it, because I don't know.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino : those additional tags were needed to make this question more interesting to more members

Comment: Ok, I have copied that `<iostream.h>' include to the project. Neat hack it is. Now the errors became weirder: non-member functions missing. The library has a lot of templates. Will be investigating.

Comment: It is not unheard of for distros to have private patches for libraries that they use, where the publicly available version isn't being updated. Or they build the binaries with an older version of compiler...